# Issues using virtual method in abstract class that returns a generic type

Tags: c#, selenium, generics, inheritance, interface

I was hoping someone might be able to help me understand a piece of code that has me partially bamboozled. It's pretty much an exact copy of the selenium loadablecomponent class

https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/dotnet/src/support/UI/LoadableComponent%7BT%7D.cs

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        C newClass = new C();
        newClass.Load().MethodInB();
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

public abstract class LoadableComponent<T> : ILoadableComponent where T : LoadableComponent<T> {
    protected abstract void ExecuteLoad();
    protected abstract bool EvaluateLoadedStatus();

    protected virtual void HandleLoadError(WebDriverException ex)
    {
    }

    public virtual string UnableToLoadMessage {
        get;
        set;
    }

    ILoadableComponent ILoadableComponent.Load()
    {
        return (ILoadableComponent)this.Load();
    }

    protected T TryLoad() {
        try {
            this.ExecuteLoad();
        } catch (WebDriverException e) {
            this.HandleLoadError(e);
        }

        return (T)this;
    }

    protected bool IsLoaded {
        get {
            bool isLoaded = false;
            try
            {
                isLoaded = this.EvaluateLoadedStatus();
            }
            catch (WebDriverException)
            {
                return false;
            }
            return isLoaded;
        }
    }

    public virtual T Load() {
        if (this.IsLoaded) {
            return (T)this;
        } else {
            this.TryLoad();
        }
        if (!this.IsLoaded) {
            //throw new LoadableComponentException(this.UnableToLoadMessage);
        }
        return (T)this;
    }
}

public class B : LoadableComponent<B> {
    protected override void ExecuteLoad() {
        //throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void MethodInB() {
    }

    protected override bool EvaluateLoadedStatus() {
        Console.WriteLine("I'm in B");
        return true;
    }
}

public class C : B {

    protected override bool EvaluateLoadedStatus() {
        Console.WriteLine("I'm in C");
        return false;
    }

    public void MethodInC() {
    }
}
```

My first question is what is this piece of code doing?

```
ILoadableComponent ILoadableComponent.Load()
{
    return (ILoadableComponent)this.Load();
}
```

It's unlike any method, property or constructor i've seen in my relatively short experience. It appears to be running/overriding the virtual method `Load()` but I can't be sure.

Second question is I thought that creating an instance of the object C and running the `Load()` method would return a type T equal to C. Instead it appears to return B, hence the `newClass.Load().MethodInB();` in my main method.

[image]

What modifications would I have to make to have the Load() method return B if I create an instance of class B and return C if I create an instance of class C?

Many thanks,

Comment: 1) Please ask *one* question per post. Your first question is basically about explicit interface implementation - please search for that term; hopefully it'll answer all your questions. 2) It sounds unlikely that your question is really anything to do with Selenium at all. Please reduce it to a [mcve] which should make things clearer.

Comment: The code example is an explicit interface implementation. It's useful when you only want to expose methods through an interface (such as `Array` explicitly implementing `IList` so that you don't call `Add` by mistake) or the class implements multiple interfaces that have members with the same signature.